# Error when typing in ng serve --open in the cmd

Tags: angular, angular9

I want to setup an Angular project by typing in the command: `ng new myapp`. Then I switched there by `cd myapp` and typed in `ng serve --open`. I installed Angular and also Node and tried out the Windows CMD but also Git Bash as CMD. By the command `ng serve --open`, an error occurs:

```
0% compiling
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 60.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 140 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 9.73 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.99 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-11T12:35:25.912Z - Hash: 8a7cea9d57d6e7ce1441 - Time: 45208ms

Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on 

http://localhost:4200/ 
: Compiled successfully.
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:4200/"' ]
```

How can I fix this, so that the Angular template appears?

My node.js version: 12.16.1.

When I type in ng version:

```
 Angular CLI: 9.0.5
    Node: 12.16.1
    OS: win32 x64

    Angular: 9.0.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.5
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.5
@angular/cli                      9.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.5
@schematics/angular               9.0.5
@schematics/update                0.900.5
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Comment: try deleting the `node_modules` folder and do `npm i` and try again

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried this, but unfortunately didn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Windown 10:
This PC -> Properties -> System protection -> tabs Advanced -> click Environment Variables -> at form System variables -> choose Path -> click Edit:

Pate all:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath

%SystemRoot%\system32

%SystemRoot%

%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\

C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin

C:\Program Files\nodejs\

click OK -> OK -> OK done